# Можно ли создавать куски JS кода в PHP цикле?

Tags: javascript, php

Нужно выводить записи с базы данных с помощью PHP. Вывожу циклом. В каждой выводимой записи должна присутствовать кнопка (JS) которая по нажатию меняет стиль выводимой записи (display: none->block).
На данный момент вывожу лишь одну запись (без цикла). Соответственно и JS код писал индивидуально под конкретную одну запись.

Вот сейчас думаю выводить сразу все записи (их более 30). Писать вручную JS код с привязкой к кнопкам для срабатывания под каждую запись считаю не логично.

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли создавать JS функции и кнопки для их срабатывания вместе с выводимой записью с БД в цикле?
В таком случае, как присвоить уникальный id каждой кнопке? 
Думаю, использовать что-то типа

```
id="block".$i."
```

Comment: Попробуй что-нибудь сделать и посмотри что получится.

Comment: @МаксимЗакревский Задумка в целом Ваша верна. Если добавите код, что пробовали сделать, то можно будет сказать конкретнее. Я бы сделал всё через класс. Например, задаём кнопке определённый класс. В `js` отслеживаем нажатия кнопок по классу, при нажатии получаем через родителя или напрямую получаем соседний элемент и меняем ему цвет. Не обязательно `id` прописывать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
<?php
$arr = ['123','123123','a','b','c'];

foreach ($arr as $value){ // Через цикл выводим поля обёрнутые в общий див с классом main
    echo '<div class="main"><div class="value">'.$value.'</div><button class="but">Скрыть/Показать</button></div>';
}
?>

<style>
    .main{
        display: block;
        width: 200px;
        background: #003eff;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .but{
        background: white;
    }
    .value{
        display: block;
    }
    .hide {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onload = function () { // При загрузке документа
        let but = document.getElementsByClassName('but'); // Получаем кнопки
        [...but].forEach(function (c) { // Для каждой...
            c.addEventListener('click', function () { // Отслеживаем нажатие
                let div = this.parentNode.children[0]; // Получаем через родителя (main) его div со значением
                div.classList.toggle('hide'); // Переключаем класс показать-скрыть
            })
        })
    }
</script>
```